# Checked checkbox ng-change not firing first time

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-change

This is my code:

```js
$scope.toggleBandPics = function(bandid){
    for (var picid in $scope.bands[bandid]['pics']) {
        $scope.bands[bandid]['pics'][picid]['show'] = ($scope.bands[bandid]['pics'][picid]['show'] == 'true'? 'false': 'true');
    }
}
```

```html
<span ng-repeat="band in bands">
    <div class="bandsfilter">
     <span ng-show="bButtons">
      <input class="checkbox"
   name="{{band.urlbandname}}"
   type="checkbox"
   id="{{band.urlbandname}}"
   ng-model="band.checked"
   ng-checked="{{band.checked}}==true"
   ng-true-value="{{band.checked}}==true"
   ng-false-value="{{band.checked}}==false"
   ng-change="toggleBandPics({{band.bandid}})"
   />
   {{band.bandname}}&nbsp;({{band.noOfPicsPerBand}})
       <span id="counter{{band.bandid}}" class="hidden">
                    {{band.noOfPicsPerBand}}
            </span>
  <span>
 </div>
</span>
<span ng-repeat="band in bands">
    <span ng-repeat="picture in band.pics">
     <div class='picture' ng-show="picture.show=='true'" ng-cloack>
      <a class="shadowbox{{picture.bandid}} photo" rel="shadowbox[{{humanconcertdate}}]" title="{{picture.bandname}}, {{humanconcertdate}}, {{venuename}}" href="/concert2/{{band.concertid}}/{{band.bandid}}/{{picture.filename}}">
    <img src="/concert2/{{picture.concertid}}/{{picture.bandid}}/{{picture.filename}}" alt="{{picture.bandname}}, {{humanconcertdate}}, {{venuename}}" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </span>
</span>
```

Now, when I run this ng-change is fired except for the first time that a checked checkbox is unchecked. When it is checked again (so when it is clicked for the second time) it does fire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Firstly**, you don't need angular expression (`{{}}`) inside `ng-`

**Secondly**, model'll be default set by value `boolean`. you don't need `ng-true-value` or `ng-false-value` to set that. If you need other value except `boolean` you can use that

Try like this

```
<input class="checkbox"
       name="{{band.urlbandname}}"
       type="checkbox"
       id="{{band.urlbandname}}"
       ng-model="band.checked"
       ng-change="toggleBandPics(band.bandid)"
/>
```

Comment: bandid does not change. Your suggestion works. But since you left out ng-checked (ng-checked="{{band.checked}}==true") the checkbox is not checked. If I add it, I am back where I started: not firing first time.

Comment: try to set value by default true it's model like this `$scope.band.checked=true`

Comment: or you wanna default checked `ng-checked='true'`

Comment: Each band entry in the model already has a band.checked=true or band.checked=false. The checkbox should be checked if band.checked=true.

Comment: then don't need to do anything. ng-model will do that task for you .. if model's value is true then checkbox will automically selected

Comment: The problem seemed to have arisen from the fact that PHP threw back 'true' as a string which is not evaluated to true in javascript. Thanks for setting me on the right track! I learned something today :)